# Can’t loosen Allen bolt from home patient lift

Tags: bolts

Hello I am trying to disassemble a hoyer lift to make space in my garage. I am already struggling though on the first bolt. It is an Allen bolt and I have a perfect Allen wrench for it. I removed the nut on the left side but the bolt isn’t coming out. I’m not sure if it is stripped inside or if there is something stopping it.

Here are pictures below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF7Ch.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there currently weight on the bolt?

Comment: What does it look like on the other side?

Comment: why would you expect the bolt unscrew when the threaded end is in air?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure containing the bolt appears to be a pivot, so the bolt shaft inside the structure is probably serving as an axle.

Did you try tapping the end of the bolt with a hammer? Use a block of hard wood between the hammer and the bolt to avoid damaging the threads.

Comment: Hey thanks so I took a rubber mallet and gave it a small hit. It went through then I was able to unscrew it completely after

Comment: Great! Glad you got it off.